# Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method toArray

Tags: java

I have a `Foo` class that extends `AbstractList` and implements `List`. This class implements some of the `List` methods, but some just throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

`toArray` is one of the later and while the compiler doesn't complain about other not really implemented methods, it complains about the `toArray` with error:

`Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method toArray(T[]) in List`.

```
public class Foo extends AbstractList implementst List  {
    ...
     public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(error);
    }
}
```

What is wrong here and why the compiler still thinks the `toArray(T[])` method is not implemented?

Comment: `toArray` is already implemented in `AbstractCollection` which `AbstractList` extends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using generic method public  T[] toArray(T[] a), you should add parameter to class signature and make it extend and implement parameterized class and interface respectively, not the raw ones. Then it will compile:

```
public class Foo<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> {

    @Override
    public <E> E[] toArray(E[] a) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error!");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Agree. Edited the answer. This way there won't be a hiding warning.

Comment: @azurefrog I wasn't addressing you.

Comment: This is somewhat unclear - the OP's code already has a parameter in the method signature.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write 'class signature', not 'method'. Edited.

Comment: java.util.Collection is actually a parameterized interface: `public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>`. All its descendants are parameterized, too. You can use raw versions, which treat their contents as Objects (it was needed to provide compatibility with pre-Java 5 classes), but in order to override parameterized method, you need to make your class parameterized, too.

Comment: If you write it like this: `public class Foo extends AbstractList implements List { public <E> E[] toArray(E[] a) throws UnsupportedOperationException {...}`, you will get an error: "Name clash: The method toArray(E[]) of type Foo has the same erasure as toArray(Object[]) of type AbstractCollection but does not override it". It's explained here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768028/name-clash-the-method-addobject-of-type-test2-has-the-same-erasure-as-adde](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768028/name-clash-the-method-addobject-of-type-test2-has-the-same-erasure-as-adde)

Answer (score -1):

This code compiles :

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo extends AbstractList implements List  {

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray(Object[] a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you use `java.util` package.

Comment: Ok, but why not `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`?

Comment: Because parameter type in super class and subclass can't be different. Here it is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: I'm not sure the relevance of that link - it's simply saying that e.g. `SomeClass<Derived>` is not a sub-type of `SomeClass<Base>`.